# Consulta SQL pegando campo dinâmico Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

Teria como fazer uma consulta sql pegando um campo digitado pelo usuário em um formulário e preenchendo automaticamente o resultado em outros campos?

Comment: Você consegue fazer isso usando AJAX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Esquema básico de como fazer uma consulta ao banco via Ajax em JavaScript puro com retorno de dados em JSON e preenchendo outros campos do formulário**

**1.) Formulário HTML**

Este formulário de exemplo tem 3 campos (`nome`, `email` e `cidade`). Ao digitar um nome e clicar em <kbd>OK</kbd>, este "nome" será enviado via Ajax para uma página PHP que fará a consulta no banco de dados e retornar 2 informações, `email` e `cidade`, relativas ao "nome" enviado.

```
<input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Digite um nome e clique OK" />
<input type="button" onclick="carrega()" value="OK" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" disabled="disabled" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" disabled="disabled" />
```

**2.) O Ajax**

No código abaixo em JavaScript, criei uma função `carrega()` que será disparada ao clique do botão <kbd>OK</kbd> do formulário. Ele envia para a página `verificar.php` (exemplo) o valor do campo `nome` do formulário e a resposta em `http.responseText` é convertida em JSON, `JSON.parse(http.responseText);`, e em seguida as informações de cada campo são preenchidas pelo seu respectivo `id`.

```
<script>
var http = false;
http = new XMLHttpRequest();

function carrega(){

   var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;

   var url_="verificar.php?nome="+nome;
   http.open("GET",url_,true);
   http.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(http.readyState==4){
         var retorno = JSON.parse(http.responseText);

         document.getElementById('email').value = retorno.email;
         document.getElementById('cidade').value = retorno.cidade;

      }
   }
   http.send(null);

}
</script>
```

**3.) PHP**

Na página PHP você receberá o valor do campo `nome` enviado pelo formulário via AJAX, fazer a consulta no banco e retornar o resultado em formato JSON:

```
<?php

$nome = $_GET['nome'];

if(isset($nome)){

   $conn = new mysqli("host", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

   $sql = "SELECT email,cidade from tabela where nome = '$nome'";

   $resultados = $conn->query($sql);

   $json = array();

   while ($rowResultados = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {

      $dados = array(
         'email' => $rowResultados['email'],
         'cidade' => $rowResultados['cidade']
      );
      $json = $dados;

   }

   echo json_encode($json);

   mysqli_close($conn);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Abaixo fiz um exemplo onde você pode modificar e enviar o valor utilizando um ajax e fazer a consulta.

> Digite no primeiro campo a palavra "mateus" e ele vai completar o
>   segundo e o terceiro.

```js
jQuery('#campo1').on('keyup',function(){
  //Aqui você pode fazer um ajax enviando o valor digitado e operar
  if(this.value == 'mateus'){
    jQuery('#campo2').val('mateus@teste.com.br');
    jQuery('#campo3').val('(81) 98615-3161');
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="campo1">
<input type="text" id="campo2">
<input type="text" id="campo3">
```